# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake', while using Python to load data

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have installed all the connectors.
While installing python I have checked on "add path in environment variable"
While running PIP list from cmd, I see the snowflake connector
(snowflake-connector-python 2.3.7
snowflake-sqlalchemy       1.2.4).

Pip list output
snowflake                  0.0.3
snowflake-connector-python 2.3.7
snowflake-sqlalchemy       1.2.4
SQLAlchemy                 1.3.22

Thanks for help.

Comment: need more info. How are you  using it? show a sample of your code

Comment: I was trying the below code to test and run first. 

#!/usr/bin/env python
import snowflake.connector as snowflake

# Gets the version
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='C8C13E2C-3CC9-4BA2-9A03-413C46022307',
    authenticator = 'externalbrowser',
    account='firstam.west-us-2.azure'
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
import snowflake.connector
```

on top to make the module recognized.

Comment: Yes, I tried. This is when it throws the error. 
I tired below code.

#!/usr/bin/env python
import snowflake.connector as snowflake

# Gets the version
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='C8C13E2C-3CC9-4BA2-9A03-413C46022307',
    authenticator = 'externalbrowser',
    account='firstam.west-us-2.azure'
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()